# Discord.js Bot giveaway command : .array() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, bots, discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord.js giveaway command that send an embed, save it to the variable embedSent, collect the reactions after the TimeOut with the reactions.get() method, convert them to an array with array() then filter them with .filter(). The problem is  at the Array() step where I keep getting the error `TypeError: peopleReactedBot.array is not a function`. 
Here is the part of my code :

```
embedSent.react("");
setTimeout(function () {
    try {
        const peopleReactedBot = embedSent.reactions.cache.get("").users.fetch();
        const peopleReacted = peopleReactedBot.array().filter(u => u.id !== client.author.id);
        message.channel.send(peopleReacted)
    } catch(e) {
        return message.channel.send("An error has occured : `"+e+"`");
    }
}, time);
```

I use Discord.js v12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.fetch()` returns a Promise, so you might want to switch to an asynchronous function and await for the promise to complete, like so :

```js
setTimeout(async () => {
    try {
        const peopleReactedBot = await embedSent.reactions.cache.get("").users.fetch();
        const peopleReacted = peopleReactedBot.array().filter(u => u.id !== client.author.id);
        message.channel.send(peopleReacted)
    } catch(e) {
        return message.channel.send("An error has occurred : `"+e+"`");
    }
}, time);
```